# DataTemplate DataType, no class, just xaml

Tags: c#, wpf

So I'm trying to understand some code we have on a project that is in C#/WPF.  I'm pretty new and just learning whatever I can.  Looking at one of the .xaml, we have a DataTemplate that lays out where things go for our app.  I want to add some events to it, but there is no code behind the .xaml since it is not a class like other .xamls in our project.  The DataType of the DataTemplate points to a ViewModel class, but this class does not see my objects in the DataTemplate.  Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Comment: Post the XAML. Otherwise, it's hard to say exactly, but you'll be using the `<Trigger>` markup to specify what to do on specific events.

Answer (score 1):

To add rich event-based behavior to elements created through XAML, you need to utilize [attached behaviors](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/AttachedBehaviors.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the attached behaviors John mentioned above, if you are using MVVM, you can utilize the commanding architecture in WPF.  Check out ICommand and implementing those on your ViewModel. You will have something like this:

Command="{Binding YourCommandName}"